# snapshotChanges() emits twice, even when the document hasn't changed

Tags: angular, angularfire

Angular firestore's document `snapshotChanges()` triggers multiple times, even when the document hasn't changed.

This issue seems to have been introduced between 6.0.5 and 6.1.0.

Here is a demo with minimal code to reproduce the issue:

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbj64s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The code is straight forward to understand:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'firestore-demo4';
  constructor( private db: AngularFirestore) {

    this.db.doc('users/85U86O7pvtFz8QUW7vbW').snapshotChanges().subscribe(t => {
      console.log(t)
    })

  }

  onClick() {
    this.db.doc('users/85U86O7pvtFz8QUW7vbW').update({
      firstName: 'john2'
    })
  }
}
```

I looked through the console logs. It looks like the metadata property `hasPendingWrites` changes from true to false during the update:

[image]

What is going on here?

I would have expected `snapshotChanges()` to fire 0 times (since the document did not change) or once, if the document did change. This is the correct and observed behavior in version 6.0.5. But in version 6.1.0 and above, `snapshotChanges()` is being triggered multiple times for metadata changes.

The issue also exists for `valueChanges()`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fb4r8p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Yes, shore answer from the Firestore team: "that's the way its supposed to work". The long answer is, its up to you to determine what's actually changed.

Comment: technically, they're not wrong... the document did change (its metadata changed). In practice, this isn't very useful if the document changes for reasons we don't care about.