# Angularfire : valuechanges observable emits twice

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

**Context :**

I'm building a chat with Angularfire 6.1.5 and firebase 8.6.1

My Firestore contains a collection "discussions". Each discussion contains a sub collection "messages".

My issue is about the new message's handler part. I need to receive the last new message created by someone and display it.

**Code :**

I'm handling new message with this observable :

```
return this.db.collection<Message>(`discussions/${id}/messages`, ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt').limitToLast(1))
      .valueChanges({ idField: '_id' })
      .pipe(...);
```

The method for adding a message :

```
sendMessage(discussionId: Discussion['_id'], message: Message): void {
    this.db.collection<Message>(`discussions/${discussionId}/messages`).add(message);
  }
```

**The problem :**

When I add just one message, `valueChanges()` emits twice. I only have one subscriber.

Is this double emission is by design or its a bug ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154310/what-is-the-difference-between-get-and-valuechanges-in-angular-firestore-que ?

Comment: Hey ! ty for your response.
Not really. I need an hot observable that emits each time a new message is created in the subcollection "messages". A message can be created by me or other users. So I can't use get() in my context

Comment: this seems related to this question without answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608321/snapshotchanges-emits-twice-even-when-the-document-hasnt-changed - but also found this issue that might help https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2336

Comment: There are some workarounds here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67514861/6513921

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Firestore subscribe() fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514628/angular-firestore-subscribe-fires-twice)

Comment: Thank you guys ! @MauricioGraciaGutierrez, your github link resolves my issue. 
Didn't know that distinctUntilChanged can takes a function with prev and current value...

Comment: Your github link resolves my issue, not your stackoverflow link.