# Angular Observable - map single values from array?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a firebase document with user data which contains ans array of project ids

I thought with this I could get every single id at once in the console log. But instead in every passthrough it logs all containing ids . Where am I mistaken?

```
const usersDocRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.userCollectionRef.doc(this.userId);

 usersDocRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(switchMap((ref) => {
      const usersProjectIds = ref.payload.data().projects;
      return from(usersProjectIds); 
      
    })).subscribe((id) => {
      console.log(id);
      
    })
```

Comment: Your code says `ref.payload.data()` returns an object (not an observable) that has a `project` property  that contains the project ids you're looking for. Is that code correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.
My intention is to 'convert' this projectIDs-property as an observable with the from-method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things, the first one is to use instead of `from` another operator called `of` that does exacly what you want, but i raccomand you to use a `map` instad of `switchMap` like the following example, because in this case there is no need to recreate an observable. Just use what you get from the response and do a map.

```
usersDocRef.snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map((ref) => ref.payload.data().projects))
.subscribe((ids) => {
  console.log(ids);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem is in the snapshotChanges()-method.

In the metadata of the payload the 'haspendingWrites'-property seems to change on every passthrough which causes a new emit for the snapshotChanges:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608321/snapshotchanges-emits-twice-even-when-the-document-hasnt-changed](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608321/snapshotchanges-emits-twice-even-when-the-document-hasnt-changed)

Now Iworked around with the get()-method.
I am not very happy with that, because I expect a more reactive app behavior with the snapshotChange.

But owed to my few experience with Angular and RxJS I just keep going with it.

```
usersDocRef.get()
.pipe(map((ref) => ref.data().projects))
.subscribe((ids) => {
  console.log(ids);
})
```

Thank you very much for everyone that has tried to help me.